# Get second to last input from %>% pipe operator

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, magrittr

I would like to make a factor out of a column I have just created **within** a pipeline.
I can do this with the following code:

```
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")
library("janitor")

iris <- iris %>% janitor::clean_names()    
iris %>% filter(species %in% c("setosa","versicolor")) %>% group_by(species) %>% 
             summarise(mean_sepal_length = mean(sepal_length)) %>% ungroup() %>%
             mutate(species = factor(species, levels = (iris %>% group_by(species) %>%  #<- works but messy
                                                            summarise(mean_sepal_length = mean(sepal_width)) %>% 
                                                            ungroup() %>% arrange(mean_sepal_length) %$% species))) %>% 
                    arrange(species)
```

I was wondering if there is "cleaner" way of doing this. Some thing like:

```
iris %>% filter(species %in% c("setosa","versicolor")) %>% group_by(species) %>% 
     summarise(mean_sepal_length = mean(sepal_length)) %>% ungroup() %>%
     mutate(species = factor(species, levels = (. %>% arrange(mean_sepal_length) %$% species))) %>% 
            arrange(species)
```

Where `.` is the **second to last argument** instead of the last argument given to the pipe?

This throws up an error because the last argument to the pipe is the mutate statement:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `species`. x 'match' requires vector arguments i Input `species` is `factor(...)`.
```

I think this is fundamentally not how the pipe operator works so this might not be possible.

Comment: knee-jerk reaction to use janitor::clean_names(). Edited post for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second option to work, we can wrap the `.` inside `{}`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
iris %>% 
 filter(species %in% c("setosa","versicolor")) %>%
 group_by(species) %>% 
 summarise(mean_sepal_length = mean(sepal_length)) %>% 
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(species = factor(species, 
      levels = ({.} %>%
                  arrange(mean_sepal_length) %$% species))) %>%
 arrange(species)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  species    mean_sepal_length
#  <fct>                  <dbl>
#1 setosa                  5.01
#2 versicolor              5.94
```

Comment: This is great! Can you elaborate on what {.} is doing? Does it pull from the second to last argument? Would {{.}} pull from third to last?

Comment: @daszlosek it is the data coming after the summarise method

Comment: @daszlosek if you meant the original data iris, it is not available at that step

Comment: @daszlosek it is not clear why you need the `factor` step, `iris %>% filter(species %in% c("setosa","versicolor")) %>% droplevels %>% group_by(species) %>% summarise(mean_sepal_length = mean(sepal_length)) %>% arrange(mean_sepal_length)`

Answer (score 0):

You can `arrange` the data based on `mean_sepal_length` and then assign `factor` levels based on their occurrence using `unique`.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  filter(species %in% c("setosa","versicolor")) %>%
  group_by(species) %>% 
  summarise(mean_sepal_length = mean(sepal_length)) %>%
  arrange(mean_sepal_length) %>%
  mutate(species = factor(species, levels = unique(species)))

#  species    mean_sepal_length
#  <fct>                  <dbl>
#1 setosa                  5.01
#2 versicolor              5.94
```